# Call a function from inside of another function in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to call snapShotTaker function from inside of HelloWorldApp function but i get `ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes` in terminal. How to solve this problem?

```
notifee.registerForegroundService(notification => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    // Long running task...
    setInterval(() => {
      HelloWorldApp.snapShotTaker();
    }, 2000);
  });
});

const HelloWorldApp = () => {
  const isAppForeground = useIsForeground();
  console.log('In Foreground?: ', isAppForeground);

  const cameraRef = useRef(null);
  const [finalPath, setPhotoPath] = useState('');

  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const device = devices.front;

  if (device == null) {
    return <ActivityIndicator style={styles.indicator} size="large" />;
  }

  const snapShotTaker = async () => {
    const snapshot = await cameraRef.current.takeSnapshot({
      quality: 20,
      skipMetadata: true,
    });
    setPhotoPath('file://' + snapshot.path);
  };
```

Comment: try to create you snapShotTaker function using `function` keyword

Comment: @TalhaJutt i tried but i got same error.

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't call it outside of the component. However you can move the notifee code to inside of your component using the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and call it there.

```js
const HelloWorldApp = () => {
  const isAppForeground = useIsForeground();
  console.log('In Foreground?: ', isAppForeground);

  const cameraRef = useRef(null);
  const [finalPath, setPhotoPath] = useState('');

  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const device = devices.front;

  if (device == null) {
    return <ActivityIndicator style={styles.indicator} size="large" />;
  }

  const snapShotTaker = async () => {
    const snapshot = await cameraRef.current.takeSnapshot({
      quality: 20,
      skipMetadata: true,
    });
    setPhotoPath('file://' + snapshot.path);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Register your service
    notifee.registerForegroundService(notification => {
      return new Promise(() => {
        // Long running task...
        setInterval(() => {
         snapShotTaker();
        }, 2000);
      });
    });

    // You need to stop the service on cleanup, so it doesn't register multiple times.
    // See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup
    return () => {
      notifee.stopForegroundService();
    };
  
  // You can pass the snapShotTaker function to the deps array but it won't affect it since it isn't memoized. See useCallback hook if you want to memoize it.
  });
```

Comment: I recommend adding an empty dependency array to the useEffect unless you want to register for the service every time something changes in the component.

Comment: I didn't want to put it in my answer since i don't know how he wants to use it, so added a comment in the closing line. But yeah, an empty array could be used if OP doesn't use (doesn't use in the question but, you know, might) variables that can change in snapShotTaker function.

Comment: @UgurEren your code is working when app is open but when i close the app i get this error:
`session/camera-not-ready: [session/camera-not-ready] The Camera is not ready yet! Wait for the onInitialized() callback!`

Comment: You need to wait for the camera to initialize as the error states. According to vision camera docs, you can pass a function to the [onInitialized prop](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/api/interfaces/CameraProps#oninitialized) and start taking snapshots when that function is called. You can do this by storing a boolean state with false default value, setting this state's value to true on the onInitialized props callback function, and checking if this state's value is true in the snapShotTaker function before calling the takeSnapshot method.

Comment: @UgurEren I asked a new question for my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017209/the-camera-is-not-ready-for-foreground-service-in-react-native

Comment: Does this definitely keep the service alive correctly, if it's placed inside a component? Docs say this: "To create a long running task, Notifee exposes a registerForegroundService method. It should be registered outside of any React components as early as possible in your code (e.g. within the project index.js file)." https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/foreground-service#building-a-long-lived-task

Comment: I actually don't know the notifee API, i just edited the question to work with `useEffect`.

Comment: I see. The official notifee docs does not recommend doing this. however, I can confirm putting 'registerForegroundService' inside a component does seem to keep the service alive